# Jenkins : sending email notification when starting a build

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, Is there a way to send a mail when starting a build. 
I know there is a post-build email notification which sends mail to the given recipients after a successful or failure build. Similarly i am expecting something like pre build notification.

Also is there a conditional email like if username == null send to xyz@domain.com else send it to requestor.

Tried : couple of plugins but didn't help much as they were post-build plugins

Answer (score 17):

1. Install the Email-ext plugin:
   https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Notice that a post build action will solve your problem even though what you intend is to send an e-mail before the build.

2. After that, go to the job configuration and "**Add Post Build Action**" > "**Editable Email Notification**"
3. Press **Avanced Settings**:
   [image: Press advanced settings...]
4. Now, at **Triggers**, just add a new trigger and choose "**Before Build**"
   [image]

For the second part, the solution is to put the recipient list in an environment variable (for example, a string parameter called **EMAIL_RECIPIENT**) and then use that in the editable email notification recipients list box as **${EMAIL_RECIPIENT}**.

Comment: thanks! got it. I have made that condition in shell script and exported that variable as environment variable and used in email_recipient column

Answer (score 0):

If you have sendmail configured, just use the "Execute shell" section and write the code to send mails before the build starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Extend Email-ext, it has the **Before build** in the **Triggers** section.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Comment: thanks , it worked. still struggling with second part of my question like adding condition statements in recipient address

Comment: @user3780647, AFAIK the plugin Extend Email doesn't support the condition as yours.

Comment: thanks for the reply! got it by doing the necessary things in shell script and exported as environment variable through which i can access that value anywhere inside the job