# How to send mail in Jenkins at the beginning of a job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We used our own custom action to send mail that once the automation has been started from Final builder. Now am using Jenkins. As long as i have searched, i found that we can send mail about Jenkins job success or failure at the end of Job. Is there any possible to send mail at the beginning of Jenkins job started? If so, what plugin do i need to use for it? Please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins : sending email notification when starting a build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641917/jenkins-sending-email-notification-when-starting-a-build)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Email Extension plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).

To configure see the article [How to send Email at every build with Jenkins](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-email). After configuring the settings follow these steps:

1. Select *Add post-build action*
2. Choose *Editable Email Notification*
3. In *Project Recipient List* you can use either default list or recipient's e-mail address
4. Select *Avanced Settings...*
5. Select *Add Trigger* and choose *Before Build*

That's it.

Comment: Am getting the below error.. What i have to do to send an email?

Comment: Connection error sending email, retrying once more in 10 seconds... Failed after second try sending email

Comment: @user2505309 make sure you entered  correct SMTP server settings.