# python script with jenkins showing html and javascript data in mail body

Tags: python, jenkins

I need to create a python script to integrate to jenkins which displays the html in mail body when the job is success, any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not that specific, so please add some information to it. Which plugin do you use? What do you mean with “display the HTML in mail body”? If you have more information to make your problem more specific, please add it. Also, I suggest going through the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use the [`python-jenkins`](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to do all jenkins related operations mentioned below:

```
1. Create new jobs
2. Copy existing jobs
3. Delete jobs
4. Update jobs
5. Get a job’s build information
6. Get Jenkins master version information
7. Get Jenkins plugin information
8. Start a build on a job
9. Create nodes
10. Enable/Disable nodes
11. Get information on nodes
12. Create/delete/reconfig views
13. Put server in shutdown mode (quiet down)
14. List running builds
15. Delete builds
16. Wipeout job workspace
17. Create/delete/update folders
18. Set the next build number
```

**EDIT 1:**

Please take a look at these [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11896118/11094041) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33665885/11094041), if you want to send it as mail.

Comment: My intention is to use python code which takes an html file(jenkins report) and after the jenkins job is success need to send a success mail with the html data as body.

Comment: Is there any problem on triggering post-build action on Jenkins job itself?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying not from jenkins directly, through a python script utilises the html report and send a mail with html body,  (as per my understanding jenkins does not allow any html content in body of email)